# Valid characters for app names

Tags: android, ios

Are there any rules that limit what characters may be used for naming apps on the Android and Apple app stores.  For instance, is there a constraint that

- restricts the name length. I have come across suggestions that a good name should have 12- characters.
- limits the name to contain only alphanumeric characters
- is it possible to use any unicode character in an app name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For iOS:**
App Store displayed name:

- 255 characters limit
- Any character or symbol (at least in the ascii range)

Bundle name (displayed under the app icon):

- Around 12 characters before it gets truncated (might be less/more since the font is not fixed size)
- Any ascii character

---

Apple review team may deny the submitted names at their discretion (avoid  ascii art `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`)

Comment: including extended Ascii, e.g. `ô`?

Comment: `ô` is fine, just don't go `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`